# How to sum an array of objects with a condition in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Hi I am doing addition of key value from objects of an array. I want to exclude the object from the addition if it has some conditions. Example:

```
var arrItem = [{"id": 1, "value":100},{"id": 2, "value":300},{"id": 3, "value":400}];

//addition
this.sum = arrItem.map((a:any) => a.value).reduce(function (a:any, b:any) {
          return a + b;
        });

console.log(this.sum) // ====>>> getting 800
```

I want to exclude object with `id==2` from summation. How I can filter this out so that I will get  result as ==> 500

Comment: `arrItem.filter()` ?

Comment: @TobiasS. I am not getting exactly how to use `filter()` here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it with reduce:

```js
this.sum = arrItem.reduce((acc, val) => {
  if (val.id !== 2) return acc + val.value;
  return acc;
}, 0);
```

Comment: I am getting NAN

Comment: @OptimistRohit https://codesandbox.io/s/wandering-leaf-i93t9p?file=/src/index.js